# Migrating to Twitter API version 1.1 (?) [duplicated]

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am quite new to Twitter API. I have updated Tweepy. I don't know what is wrong with this code and how to fix it to make it work for new version of Twitter API:

```
import oauth, tweepy 
from time import sleep

#stars is confident information
username = "*******"
password = "***********"
auth = tweepy.BasicAuthHandler(username, password)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

api.update_status('hello from tweepy!')
```

Terminal is showing me this:

```
$ python py/twi.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py/twi.py", line 11, in <module>
    api.update_status('hello from tweepy!')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 179, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 162, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp)
 tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'message': 'The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to     API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.', 'code': 68}]
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this google groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tweepy/wxUhpqPDoWQ), tweepy is supposed to support the 1.1 API. Your error message reports that tweepy is trying to use the 1.0 API. I suspect your update failed. Try uninstalling and reinstalling tweepy. What version of tweepy are you using? `tweepy.__version__` should be 2.0

Answer (score 0):

You are using basic authentication with user name and password. However, Twitter API 1.1 only supports OAuth. Here is how you authenticate with OAuth and Tweepy:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(key, secret)
```

according to [this page](http://pythonhosted.org/tweepy/html/auth_tutorial.html).